# Recommended best settings for update manager in ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: update-manager, system

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I want to know about the best and recommended settings for software update. I am asking this because it is not possible for me to update my software daily. Because I am unable to afford broadband internet connection daily due to my financial conditions. So please tell me how can I  keep my computer running good  without updating daily.

Comment: Not sure about the best (or best of the best), but the recommended settings are the default ones. How often can you update? I can't tell you that, so just update as often, as is practical for your finances.

Comment: please write how often you can use the internet or download updates. soemthing like every week, or year

Comment: @Frog3 i am using internet daily but i am using EDGE network daily. I am using broadband connection once or twice in a month.

Comment: you can just install updates as often you can, and diffrent from that you can use it normal... except there happens a bad bug... but that would mean very bad luck. But also you could fix such bad updates over EDGE

Answer (score 0):

Update Manager does not suggest daily updates by default. Only security updates pop up immediately. Other updates are suggested once a week. It is quite reasonable. But you can change these settings. But anyway you don't have to install updates every time they pop up.